# Declaring lambda function with auto in a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, auto

Is it possible to declare a lambda function in a C++ class with `auto`? I am getting a compilation error:

> error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const Temp::(lambda at a.cpp:8:29)' requires 'constexpr' specifier

I am defining a custom sort function for a set which is a class member variable, and I want to define this sort function within the class. How can I fix this?

Secondly, even if I move the lambda function line outside of the class, I am getting an error at the line where I declare the set:

> error: unknown type name 'cmp'

Why and how can I fix it?

```
class Temp {
public:
    static const auto cmp = [](int p1, int p2)
        {
            return p1>p2;
        };
    set<int, decltype(cmp) > sortedSet(cmp);
    Temp() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Semi-related: Why do you want to use a lambda expression here? A regular function would be a lot easier to write (and shorter too)

Comment: how about *use 'constexpr' specifier* as it suggest?

Comment: @appleapple That doesn't work either. It throws **error: unknown type name 'cmp'**

Comment: `sortedSet(cmp)` should also be `sortedSet{cmp}`

Comment: @UnholySheep That was another issue. It works now.

Comment: @UnholySheep I like to use lambda functions which fit for all data structures well like set, priority queue etc. with very similar usage.

Answer (score 2):

- use `constexpr` as as compiler suggest
- `std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> sortedSet(cmp)` is parse as function

  - like `int sortedSet(int);`

```
#include <set>
class Temp {
public:
    static constexpr auto cmp = [](int p1, int p2)  // <-- use constexpr
        {
            return p1>p2;
        };
    std::set<int, decltype(cmp) > sortedSet{cmp}; // <-- use uniform initialization
    Temp() {
    }
};
```

---

alternatively you can also do it with normal function

```cpp
#include <set>
class Temp {
public:
    static bool cmp(int p1, int p2) {
        return p1>p2;
    };
    std::set<int, decltype(&cmp) > sortedSet{cmp};
    Temp() {
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but got *error: unknown type name 'cmp'*. The issue was with doing  sortedSet(cmp) instead of  sortedSet{cmp}.

Comment: @apple apple Why does sortedSet(cmp) work in normal cases but not here. Why should {} be used instead of () ?

Comment: @flexter `()` never works when initializing members at class scope. Presumably because the compiler would be unable to distiguish it from member function declarations.